# I have code which run in lambda but not in python

Tags: aws-lambda

I have code which run in lambda but same is not work on my system.

```
asgName="test"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
    asgName="test"
    response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupNames=[asgName])

    if not response['AutoScalingGroups']:
        return 'No such ASG'

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

my below code i try to run in linux but prompt error "No such ASG"

```
asgName="test"
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupNames=[asgName])

if not response['AutoScalingGroups']:
    return 'No such ASG'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that you are **connecting to the correct AWS region**. If not specified, it defaults to `us-east-1` (N. Virginia). A region can also be specified in the credentials file.

In your code, you can specify the region with:

```
client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name = 'us-west-2')
```

The next thing to check is that the **credentials** are associated with the correct account. The AWS Lambda function is obviously running in your desired account, but you should confirm that the code running "in linux" is using the same AWS account.

You can do this by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which will use the same credentials as your Python code on the Linux computer. Run:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names test
```

It should give the same result as the Python code running on that computer.

You might need to specify the region:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names test --region us-west-2
```

(Of course, change your region as appropriate.)